# MYSQL Create Event

Tags: mysql

I am trying to expand my knowledge with MYsql and every time I run this via workbench, I get an syntax error but I can not seem to find it. I have been looking all over google for help with this and I did copy 2 tutorials to get to this stage.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE EVENT[IF NOT EXIST]`warning_reset` 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 WEEK
STARTS '2017-03-06 18:00:00'
  ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DO BEGIN
    call warning_script;
END */$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Error Below:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '*/' at line 7

Comment: Even if you think it's not relevant to your problem, could you please edit the question and share the full actual error message? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event creation syntax is, to put it politely, gnarly.

Here's a rewrite of your code that works.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE EVENT  `warning_reset` 
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 WEEK
    STARTS '2017-03-06 18:00:00'
    ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DO BEGIN
    call something_or_other;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

It's best to drop and recreate events rather than use `IF NOT EXISTS`. If you do use `IF NOT EXISTS` don't use square brackets.

For some reason you had `*/` in your code. That's a close-comment tag. I took it out.

Comment: Thank you, and the tutorial I used, it had it like that so it might have been an error on their be-half.